# jquery datepicker to date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery datepicker http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default.
I have to input fields like from and to date.
so in to date the from date should be present as least value in date picker.

```
<input class="user-reg-input fl" type="text" name="Duration_From[]" id="Duration_From1" value="" maxlength="25" style="width:117px;" />
<input class="user-reg-input fl" type="text" name="Duration_To[]" id="Duration_To1" value="" maxlength="25" style="width:117px;" />
```

Comment: hook @ `.change` and adapt the ranges of the counterpart

Comment: could you please be more specific

Comment: if user choose from date like 12-09-1991 then to date must be 10 yrs ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sEDXw/).

```
<input class="user-reg-input fl dt-from" type="text" name="Duration_From[]" id="Duration_From1" value="" maxlength="25" style="width:117px;" />
<input class="user-reg-input fl dt-to" type="text" name="Duration_To[]" id="Duration_To1" value="" maxlength="25" style="width:117px;" />

$('.user-reg-input').datepicker();

$('.user-reg-input.dt-from').on('change', function(el){
    console.log($(el.currentTarget).next())
    $(el.currentTarget).next().datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(el.currentTarget).val())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
$( "#Duration_From1" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: CONTEXT_PATH + "/images/icon_calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
        $( "#Duration_To1" ).datepicker("option","minDate",new Date(inst.currentYear,inst.currentMonth,parseInt(inst.currentDay)));
        $( "#Duration_To1" ).val(dateText);
    }
}); 
});
```

This is a working code snippet from my project.